# Dynamic jQuery Multi Select Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been trying to install this script to my website http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Dynamic-jQuery-Multi-Select-Tags-Input-Plugin-Fast-Select.html
But it wont work with my code

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Page</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/dist/fastselect.min.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="plugins/fastselect/dist/fastselect.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <select class="multipleSelect" multiple name="language">
        <option value="Bangladesh">Bangladesh</option>
        <option value="Barbados">Barbados</option>
        <option value="Belarus">Belarus</option>
        <option value="Belgium">Belgium</option>
    </select>

    <script>
        $('.multipleSelect').fastselect();
    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: any errors in your browser console?

Comment: @MichaelCoker Nope, Seems to be that not using Fastsearch script with it Is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [doc](http://dbrekalo.github.io/fastselect/#section-installation) one possibility is:

```js
$('.multipleSelect').fastselect();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/dbrekalo/fastselect/master/dist/fastselect.min.css">
<script src="https://rawgit.com/dbrekalo/fastselect/master/dist/fastselect.standalone.min.js"></script>


<select class="multipleSelect" multiple name="language">
    <option value="Bangladesh">Bangladesh</option>
    <option value="Barbados">Barbados</option>
    <option value="Belarus">Belarus</option>
    <option value="Belgium">Belgium</option>
</select>
```

Another possibility is to add the ***fastsearch lib***:

```js
$('.multipleSelect').fastselect();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/dbrekalo/fastselect/master/dist/fastselect.min.css">
<script src="https://rawgit.com/dbrekalo/fastsearch/master/dist/fastsearch.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/dbrekalo/fastselect/master/dist/fastselect.min.js"></script>

<select class="multipleSelect" multiple name="language">
    <option value="Bangladesh">Bangladesh</option>
    <option value="Barbados">Barbados</option>
    <option value="Belarus">Belarus</option>
    <option value="Belgium">Belgium</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you, But why is it too big?

Comment: If you refer to the style of the object  it's up to you to restyle it like you prefer.

Comment: @gaetanoM How can we select its options with jquery?(is it like <option selected='selected'></option>

Comment: @MohsenNemati In order to select, for instance the optoin with value Barbados, in jQuery you can write **$('.multipleSelect').data('fastselect').setSelectedOption($('.multipleSelect option[value=Barbados]').get(0))**  If you need to remove the selected value you can use **removeSelectedOption** instead. Bye